# Combine two window to one window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to combine two window into one window in Tkinter. I tried in many ways, I find on the web. My requirement is: if I press a button then it should create a blank screen.

Here is the code:

**1.** **main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import PIL.Image
from employee import employeeClass

class IMS:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.root.title("IMS | Developed by Amit")
        self.root.config(bg="white")
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "images\i1.png")
        self.root.iconphoto(False, photo)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    os.system('python start.py')
    root = Tk()
    obj = IMS(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**1.** **main2.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import PIL.Image

class employeeClass:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("1055x480+205+127")
        self.root.title("IMS | Developed by Amit")
        self.root.config(bg="white")
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "images\i1.png")
        self.root.iconphoto(False, photo)
        self.root.focus_force()
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        #root.overrideredirect(1)
        
        
    #-----Search-----
    SearchFrame=LabelFrame(self.root, text="Search Employee", bg="white")
    SearchFrame.place(x=250, y=20,width=600,height=70)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = employeeClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"then it should create a blank page"_ - what do you mean by "blank page"? Tkinter doesn't have the concept of pages.

Comment: do you want something like Tabs ?

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "combine two windows into one window". Do you mean to have two windows open at the same time? Or do you actually want to take everything from one window and put it into another window? Also, "start.py" is not shown as part of the code; you just show **main.py** and **main2.py**. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).